# How to move R workspace containing cyrillic symbols from Windows to Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: r, linux, windows, ubuntu, cyrillic

I am trying to read R workspace saved in Windows 7 into Ubuntu 14.04. Everything works fine, except for the Cyrillic characters contained in the objects.

I suppose the problem is due to the different types of locales, and, more specifically, the character encoding (1251 for Windows vs. UTF-8 for Ubuntu). However, I couldn't find a way to set either locale in a way compatible with the other.

setting in Windows:

```
> l10n_info()
$MBCS
[1] FALSE

$`UTF-8`
[1] FALSE

$`Latin-1`
[1] FALSE

$codepage
[1] 1251

> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Bulgarian_Bulgaria.1251;LC_CTYPE=Bulgarian_Bulgaria.1251;LC_MONETARY=Bulgarian_Bulgaria.1251;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Bulgarian_Bulgaria.1251"
```

setting in Ubuntu:

```
> l10n_info()
$MBCS
[1] TRUE

$`UTF-8`
[1] TRUE

$`Latin-1`
[1] FALSE

> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_CTYPE=bg_BG.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=bg_BG.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=bg_BG.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=bg_BG.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=bg_BG.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
```

Comment: **Update.** I found that `iconv(myvar, "WINDOWS-1251", "UTF-8")` solves the problem. Yet this seems more like a workaround for me, because I have to convert each variable individually.

Comment: Could you use ls() to show all of your variables, collect that output into an array, and then use a loop to apply iconv to each element? At least that takes out a lot of the manual effort of individual conversion.